Linux breaks Windows 11 boot
I have a dual boot system (Debian 12 + Windows 11), each in a different physical disk. I use the EFI boot menu (in the case of Linux after the EFI menu, GRUB shows up and then boots the OS).
Sometimes (like once a month, seemlingly randomly) after having used Linux, Windows doesn't boot. I select Windows in the EFI menu but it goes back to the EFI menu. Then I boot with the Windows 11 installation pendrive and fix it with bcdboot c:\windows. After it boots I can't find any useful information in Event Viewer:

or Windows Reliability Monitor. Also there is a lot of free space in the Windows partition, so I guess that the Windows shutdown process is not failing because of lack of space.
So I think the problem is not caused by Windows.
Fast Boot is disabled in Windows.
About Linux, the Windows drive is never mounted while Linux is running (it's detected but not mounted). I've checked that this happens after just using a few simple Linux apps (no updates, package installing, etc).
After one of these crashes, but before fixing it with bcdboot, I checked the EFI partition from Linux and found something weird, the file command output looks like the bootmgfw.efi is corrupted:
bootmgfw.efi: data    <------------
bootmgr.efi:  PE32+ executable

I checked the same files in a normal working Win11 system and it should be:
bootmgfw.efi: PE32+ executable
bootmgr.efi:  PE32+ executable

Any clues of something else I could check?

Can it be run from the Win11 recover environment? I can't run it in my Win11 installation if boot is broken

How old is the system's motherboard?

manufactured 2023-05

Hmmm... that likely rules out one potential issue.  I'm not sure if it will help, but whenever I run into a problem like you are experiencing, I read everything on the following site.  It's a lot to digest (which is why I've had to read it more than once), but perhaps it will help you too.  https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

In the case of two physical discs I would guess the problem would be with EFI, its bootloader, or GRUB. So I would read their documentation, how they handle two discs and if not find an answer I would try to update or downgrade them. I hypothesize that bootloader mounts both disks to each os.


any idea how often you boot Linux in a month? 2) you're certain it only happens after booting Linux, never the reverse? 3) since you advise it happens once a month could you try to not use Linux for a month to see if the problem still happens? 4) could you physically disconnect windows drive when you use Linux? My thought is since it occurs monthly these tests/results will help us understand where the problem is coming from. Maybe Linux is changing EFI on Windows disk or in motherboard boot menu, maybe it's windows just acting up monthly if the drive is failing & Linux is the red herring


5)Can you list your motherboard model? 6)do you have secure boot enabled? 7)when you say 'efi boot menu' do you mean the motherboard boot menu you access by tapping key at power on? 8)when windows fails to boot it doesn't show any errors just returns to boot menu? What happens if you truly to boot it 2x more times as that usually triggers windows repair. 9)has this setup/config worked in the past, meaning it booted to different disk OS's over a couple months with no issues? 10) if it's work fine in the past how long ago did these issues start? Do you remember any changes around issue starting?

I phrased it wrongly, it can be like 2 months withouth happening and then it happens twice in a few days. It's always after having used Linux and then going back to Windows. I can't physically disconnect the Windows drive as it is internal. Secure boot is disabled. Yes, I meant the motherboard boot menu. Windows doesn't show any error, it just goes back to that menu, like 3 or 4 times and it doesn't trigger Windows repair. It has happened mostly always since I started this dual boot setup

I am just going to post links for the moment that I think will help and maybe explain why your issue is happening.
In the coming days I'll try to update my answer with the relevant text details instead of just links.
I don't fully understand how to fix it, but it does seem to confirm the issue is Debian breaking a Windows bootloader which tracks with your experience.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758353/resolving-dual-boot-issue-windows-not-showing-in-grub-menu#758369
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/17okwtv/installed_debian_now_i_cant_boot_windows_anymore/
https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#rc-bugs
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=945001
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=913916
https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#grub-os-prober

